# python-telegram-bot indexing a file library (videos and photos)

Tags: python-telegram-bot

i am using python-telegram-bot 8

i am trying to make a database (mysql) indexing all files (videos and photos) that are sent by users in a telegram supergroup to say a warn if someone send a file that already was sent.

videos and photos has the attribute 'file_id' but this file_id is different if 2 person send the same file.

is there anyway to have a unique identifier for a file sent to a group?

Videos:

update.message.video.file_id

update.message.video.file_size

update.message.video.duration

Photos:

update.message.photo[2].file_id

update.message.photo[2].file_size

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get unique identifier of file, you need to download it, and calculate hash of it. :(

BTW, you can make a suggestion to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport), development team may add this attribute in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_info = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)
downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
src=os.path.join(str(user_id),'input.mp4')
with open(src, "wb") as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

this code will save the video file in the src path